# Are the positive and comparative versions of an adjective different adjectives or different forms of the same adjective?

Tags: adjective

I am trying to figure out the difference between a word and a form of a word.

Which is the comparative version of an adjective in the positive degree:

- an adjective different from the adjective, or
- a form of the adjective?

In English, is it correct that *good* and *better* are two different adjectives, instead of two forms of the same adjective?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about Latin, or English?

Comment: Either way, you'll need to be more specific about what counts as the "same" word. Are _amō_ and _amat_ different words? How about _sum_ and _esse_? _Ferre_ and _tulī_? _Fiō_ and _faciō_?

Comment: This might be better suited to Linguistics. But there's no answer here, as it could be either depending on one's interpretation. It's completely subjective. I will say though that usually when the comparative form (or other forms) come from a different root (like the English "good" and "better"), they're seen as two different words, with the latter taking the role of the missing form of the former.

Comment: @cmw Lexicographers mostly treat them as the same word, i.e., there is no separate entry for *melior* or *optimus*, etc.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Traditional lexicography, yes, although some dictionaries do have separate entries (with a note saying "see *X*). I understood the question in light of linguistics, but certainly a lexicographic approach is equally valid.